# Предложите альтернативу AIMS Script Editor

Tags: c#, .net

Я разрабатываю API для одного приложения. И нужно прикрутить скриптовый движок, чтобы из скрипта можно было вызывать API. Очень желательно чтобы в скриптах было автодополнение, подсветка синтаксиса и отладка. Я нашел такое решение: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27744/Net-Script-Editor-C-Vb-net-Mini-IDE
Но оно имеет много багов.

Кто-нибудь может предложить альтернативу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал в качестве альтернативы Scintilla (на которой построен Notepad++), но как показала практика, так-же глючит изредка (по крайней мере в 2010 году было так).
Хотя, можете попробовать - проект активно развивается, ошибки могли поисправлять.

Вот тут сайт проекта: [ScintillaNET](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/), документации совсем немного, но из примеров (идут в комплекте) в основном всё понятно.